# How do I properly extend React Bootstrap components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Say I have a badge component I want to add sizing for. This is how I currently do it:

```
import React from 'react';
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/Badge';
import classNames from 'classnames';

const BadgeExtended = props => {
  const {className, size, ...attr} = props;
  const classes = classNames(
    className,
    size && `badge-${size}`
  );

  return <Badge className={classes} {...attr}>{props.children}</Badge>;
};

export default BadgeExtended;
```

which works OK. Is that a correct way to do it? Is there a way to extend the original component so that I dind't have to import an extended one, using `react-bootstrap/Badge` instead?

Comment: i am learning reactjs from couple of week . Even after writting some scratch codes andd few small projects i feel this code is so different from way i write ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way you came up with is the right way. If you look at the repository ([here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Badge.js)), the Badge component is functional, not a class, so there's no way to use the extend keyword.

Making [an HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) seems like the best way to achieve what you're doing.